# sumar valores de un arreglo con recursividad

Tags: java, array, recursión

Tengo que realizar la suma de los valores de un arreglo utilizando recursividad (ejercicio p/universidad) no estoy pudiendo hacer la llamada recursiva pasando una arreglo, les dejo el código por si me pueden dar una mano.

Código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EjercicioDoce {


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("Cuantos numeros quiere ingresar?");
        int arr[] = new int[sc.nextInt()];

        System.out.println("Cargar los Valores :");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println(sumarValores(arr));
    }



        public static int sumarValores(int array[]) {
            int tam = array.length;
            int rta;
            if (tam == 0){
                return 1;
            }else{
                 rta = (array[tam]) +  sumarValores(array[tam-1]);;

            }
            return rta;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

el problema que tienes está en la llamada del método ya que el método requiere un **array** como parámetro de entrada pero en la línea `rta = (array[tam]) +  sumarValores(array[tam-1]);` el `array[tam-1]` lo qué está recuperando es el valor en la posición **tam-1** del **array** (Un número en este caso)

**Una posible solución seria la siguiente:**

> **EDITADO:** Añadido comentarios al código.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Cuantos numeros quiere ingresar?");
        int arr[] = new int[sc.nextInt()];

        System.out.println("Cargar los Valores :");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        // LLAMADA A LA FUNCIÓN PARA SUMAR LOS VALORES DE UN ARRAY DE FORMA RECURSIVA
        System.out.println(sumarValores(arr, arr.length - 1));
    }

    // EL MÉTODO RECOGERÁ EL ARRAY Y LA POSICIÓN DEL ELEMENTO A SUMAR
    public static int sumarValores(int array[], int posArray) {
        // INICIALIZAMOS UNA VARIABLE CON LA POSICIÓN DEL ARRAY ((NO ES NECESARIO)) 
        int tam = posArray;
        int rta;
        /* COMPROBAMOS QUE ÉL TAMAÑO DEL NO SEA CERO, YA QUE SI EL TAMAÑO
        ES CERO INTENTARÁ EN LA SIGUIENTE LLAMADA ENTRAR EN LA POSICIÓN -1
        DEL ARRAY DANDO UN ERROR */
        if (tam == 0) {
            return array[tam];
        } else {
            /* SI EL TAMAÑO NO ES IGUAL A CERO, AÑADIMOS AL RESULTADO
            LA SUMA DEL VALOR PASADO POR PARÁMETRO MÁS EL VALOR DE LA 
            POSICIÓN ANTERIOR */
            rta = (array[tam]) + sumarValores(array, tam - 1);

        }
        return rta;
    }
```

> **Nota:** Se está llamando al método (función) empezando por la última posición del array y decrementando hasta la primera, cuando el
>   ***array[0]***

**Ejemplo:**

Si tenemos un array de 5 posiciones cargado con 5 número y se llama a la función

```
int array[] = {2,4,1,3,5};
int posicionAnterior = array.length;
sumarValores(array, posicionAnterior);
```

La función realizará la siguiente operación en este orden:

1. Entrará e inicializará el parametro `int tam`
2. comprobará si el tamaño es igual a cero o no*(la primera vez en este ejemplo no lo es)*
3. Entonces pasará por el *else* y sumará el array[tam], que será 5 la primera vez, con lo devuelto por la función

La función entrará de manera recursiva hasta llegar al primer valor del array caundo `array[0]` *(que en este ejemplo vale 2)*. A partir de este punto subirá Devolviendo "2" y sumándolo al valor desde donde fue llamado (en este caso la siguiente posición que vale 4). Pasará así a un paso superior sumando los valores devueltos:

1. Cuando **array[0] return -> 2**
2. Cuando **array[1] return -> 2+4**
3. Cuando **array[2] return -> 6+1**
4. Cuando **array[3] return -> 7+3**
5. Cuando **array[4] return -> 10+5**

Comment: @LuiggiMendozaJ, Vale, comentado. espero haberlo explicado bien, si no está del todo claro lo intentaré explicar de otra forma.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda!! para ver si me queda claro, lo que estaba haciendo mal era en los parametros que use en la función que se llama recursivamente,solo estaba pansando tengo que pasar un arreglo y una posición o el tamaño del arreglo? es decir el possArray seria el tamaño del arreglo?

Comment: Hola @MaxiHernandez, te añado un ejemplo para explicarlo en la respuesta

Comment: @MaxiHernandez, respondiendo a tu pregunta, le tienes que pasar el arraglo y la última posición del array

Comment: excelente mas que claro!!